# How to parse suburb from unstructured address string

Tags: python, parsing

Python noob here.

I am working with a large dataset that includes a column with unstructured strings. I need to develop a way to create a list that includes all of the suburb names in Australia (I can source this easily). I then need a program that parses through the string, and where a sequence matches an entry in the list, it saves the substring to a new column. The dataset was appended from multiple sources, so there is no consistent structure to the strings.

As an example, the rows look like this:

```
GIBSON AVE PADSTOW NSW 2211
SYDNEY ROAD COBURG VIC 3058
DUNLOP ST, ROSELANDS
FOREST RD HURSTVILLE NSW 2220
UNKNOWN   
JOSEPHINE CRES CHERRYBROOK NSW 2126
```

I would be greatly appreciative if anyone has any example code that they can share with me, or if you can point me in the right direction for the most appropriate tool/method to use.

In this example, the expected output would look like:

'Padstow'

'Coburg'

'Roselands'

'Hurstville'

''

'Cherrybrook'

---

EDIT:

Would this code work?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
suburb_list = np.genfromtxt('filepath/nsw.csv', 
                          delimiter=',', dtype=str)
top_row = suburb_list[:].tolist()

dataset = pd.read_csv(‘filepath/dataset.csv')

def get_suburb(dataset.address):
    for s in suburb_list:
        if s in address.lower()
            return s
```

Comment: Specify the expected result too!

Comment: Thanks :) I've added the expected output to the OP

Answer (score 0):

So for a pretty simple approach, you could just use a big list with all the suburb names in lower case, and then do:

```
suburbs = [ 'padstow', 'cowburg', .... many more]

def get_suburb(unstructured_string):
    for s in suburbs:
        if s in unstructured_string.lower()
            return s
```

This will give you the first match. If you want to get fancy and maybe try to get it right in the face of misspellings etc., you could try "fuzzy" string comparison methods like the [Levenshtein distance](https://www.python-course.eu/levenshtein_distance.php) (for which you'd have to separate the string into individual words first).